# The practical usage of Arnold Matrix Trace Theorem

Tags: matrices, number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, trace

I would like to ask about the Arnold's Matrix Trace theorem:
$$\textrm{tr}\big(A^{p^k}\big)\equiv\textrm{tr}\big(A^{p^{k-1}}\big)\ (\!\!\bmod  {p^k}).$$
This theorem looks fantastic to me. But is there any practical usage of it or maybe some algorithm based on this?

EDITED:
Adding some reference:

https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/fermats-little-theorem-for-matrices/

Comment: Is $A$ an integer matrix or what?

Comment: Yes. The  $A$ is an integer matrix.

Comment: see [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=LqvLnu8c3ToC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=arnold%27s+matrix+trace+theorem&source=bl&ots=l3ONCuHuob&sig=fERhRMLB6AEJsB9cbAL35Hphim8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBv67NocXcAhUrqlkKHWuPB20Q6AEwCHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=arnold's%20matrix%20trace%20theorem&f=false)